# WordPress website's home page not working after move from local to live server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a website on WordPress on my local server. After that, I transferred it from my local server to the live server i.e. Hostinger. My website is over 300 MB so to transfer the files I used the "All-in-One-WP-Migration" plugin. I also saved the permalinks after moving the website. All pages on my website are working except the home page. This is the first time I don't know how it is possible. I hosted my website 2 days ago i.e. 20-11-23. I have taken the domain from GoDaddy. And I also changed the Nameserver. I have used the "Astra" theme and the website shows me the default home page. Please help me to overcome this issue. Currently, the following page is being displayed-

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with reactive your theme?